# Proving a metric space with binary functions

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, metric-spaces, binary

Let $2^ \omega$ be the set of all infinite binary sequences, i.e., sequences of zeros and
ones. Define the function $d: X \times X \rightarrow [0, \infty)$ as follows:

$$
d(x,y) = \text{inf} \{2^{-n} ~|~ x=_n y\}
$$

where $x =_n y$ means that the first n terms of $x$ agree with those of $y$. 
For example,  let $0^\omega = 000\cdots, \text{and} ~ 001^ \omega =00111 \cdots, \text{then}~ 0^\omega =_2 001^ \omega.$

Prove that $(X, d)$ satisfies $d(x,z) \leq \max \{d(x,y), d(y,z)\}$. 
Hence, show that $(X,d)$ is a metric space.

My answer: showing the first few properties of metric space is trivial. But how to prove that inequality? what is the infimum of $2^{-n}$ ?

Comment: Restate the expression $d(x,z) \leq \max \{d(x,y), d(y,z)\}$ in terms of how many places $x$,$y$, and $z$ agree with each other. See if you can figure it out from there.

Comment: "What is the infimum of $2^{-n}$?" What do you mean by this? It seems like you're asking about what the definition of $d$ means, but you've provided two examples of calculations of $d$, as well as proven some properties about $d$ already. Could you share your proof that, for example, $d(x, y) = 0 \implies x = 0$?

Comment: @user754697 That is not what is written. What is written is $\inf$ of a set, the set $\{2^{-n}\mid x=_n y\}$.

Comment: @flan Look at the last sentence. (Also, regarding my last comment, I meant $x = y$, not $x = 0$.)

Comment: @flan so what is inf of a set 2^-n ???

Comment: If the two sequences agree in the first $n<\infty$ places, then the infinum is taken as $\inf\{2^0,2^{-1}, \cdots 2^{-(n-1)},2^{-n}\}=2^{-n}$. If they agree at all entries, then we have $\inf \{2^0,\cdots,2^{-1000},\cdots\}=0$

Comment: Maybe it's easier if you realise that $d(x,y)=2^{-(n+1)}$ where $n$ is the first coordinate where $x_n \neq y_n$  (if $x \neq y$) and $d(x,y)=0$ if $x=y$. The $\inf$ formulation is to avoid the special case of equality. But the values are the same with my definition.